# Wurth transformer secondary pins on left and right side of transformer

Tags: transformer, isolation

I am looking to use Wurth Transformer 750310988 and I have noticed its pinout is very bizarre. My application is I want to float the secondary of this transformer up to 500VDC and provide a isolated 50V supply rail floating at 500V. Normally transformers have one side as the primary and another side as the secondary and creepage and clearance is across the entire transformer body. However, there transformer I am looking at has a center pin (pin 5) on the primary side as per the image below.

Is this correct, and would this mean I would need to maintain creepage and clearance between pin 5 and pin 3 on the primary side?

[image]

Comment: You shouldn't use this transformer. It's designed for 12V input and 48V output.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Certainly looks that way. If you [look](https://www.we-online.com/components/products/datasheet/750310988.pdf) at the chips it is designed to work with they are low voltage to low voltage so they may not have considered high primary-secondary voltage likely (though they do say they test to 1500VAC).

You could have a PCB slot milled through where pin 4 is (or should be) but I suspect the transformer itself won't have acceptable creepage and clearances.